# Android MediaPlayer displays black screen in some devices

Tags: android, media-player

I have an application that plays a video from the sdcard with MediaPlayer. I have used Android Developers example (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html), and it works great in some devices: HTC Desire (Android 2.2), HTC Legend (Android 2.2).

However, I have tried it in a Samsung Galaxy 5 (Android 2.1) and it doesn't display the video, just a black screen.
No errors in LogCat.

Any ideas about why does this happen?

Thanks in advanced,

Marta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you developed the app with focus on 2.2?
Probably there were some changes from 2.1 in this part. You could check the older API demos (they are all in your sdk fodler) and look for changes from rev. 7 to 8.

However I prefer to use the VideoView http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html

Worked allot better on everything I made yet.

Comment: I have developed and build with 1.5 and I have used the MediaPlayer example from API 7 (Thre aren't changes from 7 to 8). My first attempt was with VideoView but I had some problems.

Comment: Finally I have tried again with VideoView and I realise that I have the problem with the video format, so I have convert my mp4 video to 3gp and it works great!!! Thank you very much!!!